# Reading shop list from txt file in Python

Tags: arrays, string, file, python-2.7, struct

I'm really fresh to Python and need help reading information from txt file. I have a large C++ app need to duplicate it in Python. Sadly I have no idea where to start. I've been reading and watching some tutorials, but little help from them and I'm running out of time.

**So my task is:**
I have a shopping list with:

> *-Name of the item, price and age.*

I also need to create two searches.

1. Search whether the item is in the shop (comparing strings).

`if name of the item is == to the input name.`

2. Search by **age**. Once the program finds the items, then it needs to print the list according to the price - from the lowest price to the highest.

> For example you input age 15 - 30, the program prints out appropriate
>   items and sorts them by the price.

Any help would be nice. At least from where I could start.
Thank you.

---

**EDITED**

---

So far, I have this code:

```
class data:
    price = 0
    agefrom = 0
    ageto = 0
    name = ''

# File reading
def reading():
    with open('toys.txt') as fd:
        toyslist = []
        lines = fd.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            information = line.split()
            print(information)
            """information2 = {
                'price': int(information[1])
                'ageftom': int(information[2])
                'ageto': int(information[3])
                #'name': information[4]
            }"""
            information2 = data()
            information2.price = int(information[0])
            information2.agefrom = int(information[1])
            information2.ageto = int(information[2])
            information2.name = information[3]

            toyslist.append(information2)
    return toyslist

information = reading()
```

**I HAVE A PROBLEM WITH THIS PART. I want to compare the user's input with the item information in the txt file.**

```
n_search = raw_input(" Please enter the toy you're looking for: ")

def name_search(information):
for data in information:
    if data.name == n_search:
print ("We have this toy.")
else:
    print ("Sorry, but we don't have this toy.")
```

Comment: Well, you probably need a `for` loop, comparison `==` or `item in []` as Will pointed out and reading from files that's done like this: `with open("myFileName.txt","r") as inFile: records = inFile.readlines()`. `records` will hold all the lines from the file i.e. `-Name of the item, price and age.`.

Comment: name_search is used as a variable and as a function name in your example. One is going to override the other

Comment: I did a mistake translating this program. In my original code the variable's and function's names were different. Like I've mentioned, It says error in for loop. and i can't understand why :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to fins something in a list it's generally as straightforward as:

```
if "apple" in ["tuna", "pencil", "apple"]
```

However, in your case, the list to search is a list of lists so you need to "project" it somehow. List comprehension is often the easiest to reason about, a sort of for loop in a for loop.

```
if "apple" in [name for name,price,age in [["tuna",230.0,3],["apple",0.50,1],["pencil",1.50,2]]]
```

From here you want to start looking at filters whereby you provide a function that determines whether an entry is matched or not. you can roll your own in a for loop or use something more functional like 'itertools'.

Sorting on a list is also easy, just use 'sorted(my_list)' supplying a comparator function if you need it.

---

Examples as per your comment...

```
class ShoppingListItem:
   def __init__(self,name,price,age):
      self.name=name
      self.price=price
      self.age=age
```

or

```
from collections import namedtuple
sli = namedtuple("ShoppingListItem",['name','age','price'])
```

Comment: In C++ I was doing so with structures. Defying the item with "name, price and age". Is it possible to do similar thing here? o.o Because the details about the item need to be "stuck" together.

Comment: Yes. There a few ways. Make a class or use named tuples

Comment: Thank you for a kick-start. It really helped me!

Comment: Feel free to mark the answer as correct if you choose

Comment: Hey, I have a question with for loop, I edited the main post and added some code. I would be happy If you could tell me what I am doing wrong ...